# How to ignore special characters in to_tsquery search (Postgresql)

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, full-text-search

I want to implement a full-text search using postgres where users can find news by title.

Now I have it implemented like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * " +
            "FROM content, " +
            "to_tsquery(concat(regexp_replace(trim(:search), '\\W+', ':* & '), ':*')) as q " +
            "WHERE make_tsvector(title, title_original, title_other, title_jp) @@ q " +
            "ORDER BY ts_rank(make_tsvector(title, title_original, title_other, title_jp), q) DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Content> searchContentByTitle(@Param("search") String search, Pageable pageable);
```

Where is the main problem - `to_tsquery(concat(regexp_replace(trim(:search), '\\W+', ':* & '), ':*'))`
If the user enters any special character in the search query, for example (`cats &`) - this will cause an error or break the search.

Is there a way to escape special characters before inserting them into a query? Is there a java tool for this? How can this be solved with postgresql?

Comment: If you are using to_tsquery directly, then is is expected that you know what you are doing.  If you make an error, then you get an error.  There are more robust variants (names ending in 'to_tsquery') more suitable for casual users.

Comment: @jjanes Thanks for the comment. I've looked at other to_tsquery alternatives like (websearch_to_tsquery or plainto_tsquery) but they don't seem to have the ```:* ```operator I need.